# CSS para mensagens A e B

Tags: css

Tenho as seguintes `span` com mensagens trocadas entre um utilizador A e um B. Como posso configurar estas spans para aparecerem cada uma em sua linha. Da maneira que eu tenho o estilo da `span` ele sobrepõe as mensagens na mesma linha.

```
<div class="jd-user">           
<div class="jd-header" id="44">marisa09 •<span class="close-this"> X </span></div>          
<div class="jd-body"><span class="me"> <span class="me"> Oii </span><span class="me"> teste </span>
<span class="me"> Olá </span>
<span class="other"> Oi </span>

<span class="me"> oii </span></span></div>          
<div class="jd-footer"><input id="textareabox" placeholder="escrever...">  </div>       
</div>
```

Estilo:

```
#jd-chat .jd-body {
overflow: scroll;

min-height: 250px;
background: #FFFFFF;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

#jd-chat .jd-body  span.me
{   


background:#DB3256;
display:block;
border-radius: 25px;
color:white;

}

#jd-chat .jd-body span.other
{
background: #337ab7;
display:block;
float:right;
border-radius: 25px;

}
```

Minha outra duvida é, tendo o `body` do chat com 250px de largura maxima, como posso fazer com que a mensagem se faça um paragrafo quando atingir os 250px no `body`

```
#jd-chat .jd-body

{
overflow: scroll;

max-height:250px;
min-height:250px;
background:#FFFFFF;
overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu código - não sei se ficou faltando `css` - não funcionou pois as classes começam com o id `#jd-chat` mas o `html` não possui essa definição, logo o `css` nunca está sendo aplicado ao `html`.

Outro ponto que notei, foi que você está englobando tanto o `span.me` como `span.other` DENTRO de um `span.me`, ou seja, ele não vai ter o resultado que você deseja.

Seu HTML seria melhor organizado assim:

```
<div class="jd-body">
    <div>
        <span class="me"> Oii </span>
        <span class="me"> teste </span>
        <span class="me"> Olá </span>
        <span class="other"> Oi </span>
        <span class="me"> oii </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

e o css:

```
.jd-body {
    overflow: scroll;
    max-height: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.jd-body span {
    display:block;

    /*-apenas para estilo-*/
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:4px 8px;
    color: white;
}
.jd-body  span.me{   
    background:#DB3256;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.jd-body span.other {
    background: #337ab7;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Veja este exemplo do código arrumado: https://jsfiddle.net/4kfgq8L9/

---

Veja este exemplo, para deixar um pouco mais bacana o layout: https://jsfiddle.net/4kfgq8L9/1/

Apenas coloquei cada `span` dentro de uma `div.linha`, esta div tem largura 100% e o `span` possui a largura somente do texto dentro dele, com um `float` para esquerda ou direita, dependendo se é `.me` ou `.other`

Comment: Obrigado (y) era mesmo isso. Tenho uma outra duvida, vou postar no meu post, talvez também me possa ajudar.

Comment: Ao dizer 'fazer um parágrafo' você quis dizer deixar aquele texto dentro de um único span, e o que for o restante jogar para outro span? Seria isso?

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. sim, queria que fosse para um outro span

Comment: Somente com css acredito que não seja possível, teria que utilizar javascript para isso. Mas aconselho a fazer outra pergunta, para não misturar as coisas. =D